# git track concatenated files

Tags: git, concatenation

I like to concatenate several files scattered over a tree into a single file and remove them afterwards.

Is it possible to have git track this concatenation, so that the history of all concatenated files can be obtained by `git log the_concated_file` ?

Comment: why just not use `git log file1 file2 file3` ?

Comment: because the files would be replaced by the concatenation and so no user will know where the history of the concatenated code lines is.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible in git. Moving files is supported, but concatting files not.

Answer (score 0):

git won't concatenate a file. As mentioned you can use `git log file1 file2 file3`. Another approach is to simply `cat` the files you need to a new file.

```
cat old.file another.file > new.file
```

Afterwards you will simply add the `new.file` to your tracked files. Now every time you use the same `cat`, all the three files will be shown as modified and can be staged for the next commit and you will also see the changes of all the three files.

Comment: But I like to get rid of the old files. I clarify this.